# Running php inside screen with parameters?

Tags: php, gnu-screen

i am running a php file that takes up to `2-4` hours to run, and because my internet is so bad i will need to run it inside a linux server (screen). My question is: How can i run php file inside screen with using `"GET"`, because when i use parameters it wont run. it could be that some char are reserved to linux bash, like `"?"`, `"&"`, if so is there any way escaping thos char or is there any other solution? i dont want to create single php file for every parameters.

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking. Can you give a code example?

Comment: i cannot run this 

#screen
#php baseurl/filename.php?`type=hi`

i can only run single php file not with parameters

Comment: Inside your screen? Whut?

Comment: For others - [`screen`](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html) is a unix command for running commands in a non-terminating away in a terminal that persists across logins.

Comment: yes inside screen with ssh

Answer (score 3):

You could use [PHP CLI](http://www.php-cli.com/) for this and get the parameters with [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).
Read more [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/command-line-arguments-php-cli/).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HTTP request in screen with lynx or wget.

```
wget http://yourserver.com/yourscript.php?paramter1=1....
```

Comment: but i will need to see the callbacks